# Routing audio from any program through WSLg

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, programming

I have the latest version of WSL2 with Ubuntu22.04 installed. I would like to use wsl to write some c programs which need to be able to produce audio. My library of choice for this is PortAudio.

Sadly portaudio does not recognize any audio devices and is thus unable to produce sound.
Their "saw wave" example fails citing no devices being found, a their "list devices" example returns 0 devices.
Other apps that are expected to (eg firefox) do produce sound.

As I understand it WSL2 does not use virtual audio devices but instead connects to WSLg which runs a pulseAudio server and interfaces with Windows.

I guess my general question would be, given a program looking for an audio device, how can I hook it up so the audio it tries to produce is routed to my windows system.